# Setting up multi-stage Docker build on Heroku

Tags: docker, github, heroku, dockerfile, spacy

[Edit: It looks like my specific question is how to push a multi-stage Docker build to Heroku]

I'm trying to set up a NLP server using the [spacy-api-docker](https://github.com/jgontrum/spacy-api-docker/blob/master/docker/en/Dockerfile) Github repository.

The project README lists a base image (jgontrum/spacyapi:base_v2) with no included language models as well an English language model image (jgontrum/spacyapi:en_v2) which is what I'm looking for.

When I pull and run the English language image the localhost API works perfectly, but when I try to build an image from the cloned Github repository the main Dockerfile seems to only build the base model (which is useless), and when I follow the steps listed in [this heroku docker documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-multiple-images) and [this other third party tutorial](https://medium.com/travis-on-docker/how-to-run-dockerized-apps-on-heroku-and-its-pretty-great-76e07e610e22) to push the container to Github it only seems to use that base Dockerfile - I can get the api running but it's useless with no models.

The repository also has a bunch of shorter language-specific Dockerfiles in a subfolder which I'm guessing need to be specified in some way? Just sticking the english Dockerfile after the main Dockerfile didn't work, at any rate.

My guess is that I might have to:

- a. figure out how to push an image from Docker hub to Heroku without
  a repository (the only image that's worked completely I pulled
  directly from docker)
- b. figure out how to make a repository from a
  pulled image, which I can then make into a Heroku project with heroku
  create
- c. figure out how to specify the :en_v2 part when I build to
  Heroku from the repository (is that a Docker tag? does it somehow
  specify which additional Dockerfile to use?)
- d. look into multi-stage Docker builds

I'm new to programming and have been banging my head against this for a while now, so would be very grateful for any pointers (and please pardon any terms I've used poorly, my vocabulary is pretty basic for this stuff).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I can help you is just show sample code if just you wanna know how to setup multistage build and how to build.

I'm also using multistage build on Docker because several containers are required on this system and just show you related source code as below.

- multistage build on Dockerfile
  https://github.com/hiromaily/go-goa/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile.multistage.heroku
- how to deploy to Heroku from travis-ci in my case
  https://github.com/hiromaily/go-goa/blob/master/.travis.yml

I didn't read carefully, so if I miss that point, please ignore me.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I tried again with a clean slate and it worked, I all of my past attempts were mucking up the build.